# Dot Matrix Printer Source Code Syntax Highlighting

Tags: printing, formatting, syntax-highlighting, code

I am using an OKI Microline 3390 to print out things from my linux box. I am using it as a text-only printer. No graphics, no PDF, no ghostscript ... A text file, say, is sent to the printer as a stream of character codes. The printer `sees' ISO-8859-1 (latin 1) code 65 and then prints out an 'A' character ... Seems to be necessary to go a bit into detail, since these kind of devices seem to have vanished out of (or have never been in) some people's minds.

So ... I would like to not only send text files to the printer, but c source code files. Here comes my question:

How do I accomplish to have the print out a syntax highlighted appearance?

Comment: What have you tried, what research have you done, have you read the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656914/printing-code-with-syntax-highlighting) I've commented under your last (same) question which got closed?

Comment: How do you expect an answer when you don't even provide the Operating System (and version) that you are running? We are not mind-readers. Please [edit] the question and provide this essential information. Do not reply in the comment section.

Comment: what would syntax highlighting even look like in a monochromatic form? control statements in bold, variable names in italic, method names in strikethrough?

Comment: You need a colour printer for syntax highlighting. You have a black and white printer.

Comment: Yes, mashuptwice, I have read your link. This does not answer my question since it is not about (almost) raw text output. Postscript, etc is not related to my question here.

Comment: Dear David, I kindly ask you to keep calm, friendly and humble. This is not about someone’s personal state. The information given should be sufficient to start an interesting exchange. Should you aim for a personal vendetta---for what ever reason---please, look for somebody else.

Comment: Hi Frank. Yes, you can do monochrome syntax highlighting. The fact, that you perhaps don’t like it or cannot imagine how it looks is not important.
Same goes for David. You do not _need_ a color printer to highlight text in some way.

But again, dear fellows, this is not an argument about personal taste. I am asking how it is possible to achieve this, not if you personally like it.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @DennisWydra Please add your operating system, example input and example output to your question, as it is currently unclear how you would like the printed document to look. Also I kindly ask you to keep the discourse on a professional level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use *GNU Source-highlight* ([Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html)):

Create an output language definition (e.g., ‘epsonlq.outlang’):

```
# file epsonlq.outlang
extension "txt"

bold "\x1bE$text\x1bF"
underline "\x1b-1$text\x1b-0"
italics "\x1b4$text\x1b5"
```

Create an output style definition (e.g., epsonlq.style)

```
keyword black b ;
type, classname black ;
string black ;
regexp black ;
specialchar black ;
comment black i ;
number black ;
preproc black b ;
symbol black ;
function b;
cbracket black;
variable black ;

// line numbers
linenum black;

// other elements for ChangeLog and Log files
date black ;
time black ;
ip black ;
file black ;
name black ;

// Internet related
url black u;

// for diffs
oldfile black;
newfile black;
difflines black; 

// for css
selector black;
property black;
value black i;

// for feature (Cucumber) files
cuketag black ;
gherken black ;
given black ;
when black ;
then black ;
and_but black ;
table black ;
```

Create the file to be sent to the printer containing the highlighted code in the printer’s ‘language’:

```
source-highlight -s c --outlang-def epsonlq.outlang \
    --style-file epsonlq.style <source.c >epsonlq.out
```

Print the file

```
lp -d <print-queue> -o raw epsonlq.out
```

One example how to highlight code printed on a dot matrix printer:

[image: One example how to highlight code printed on a dot matrix printer.]